# How does function c2d in MATLAB manage fractional delay?

Tags: matlab, filters, z-transform, delay, zoh

the function c2d allows to convert a continuous laplace transfer function to a discrete z-transform transfer function. The base method is the Zero Order Holder. In example:

```
   s=tf('s');
   P=3/(3+s);
   Pd=c2d(P,0.1); % 0.1 is the sampling time
```

Produces

$$ \frac{0.25918178 }{z - 0.74081822068} $$

$0.74081822068 = e^{-0.1 \ \cdot \ 3}$ as expected.

If we had a delay to the tf such as

$$ e^{-2 s} \ \frac{3}{3+s} $$

the conversion will result obviously in:

$$ z^{-20} \ \frac{0.25918178 }{z - 0.74081822068}$$

But if we introduce a delay not multiple of $0.1$ like this:

$$ e^{-1.95 \ s} \ \frac{3}{3+s} $$

it will produce:

$$ z^{-20} \ \frac{0.1393 z + 0.1199}{z - 0.7408} $$

As stated [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/continuous-discrete-conversion-methods.html), for *"ZOH Method for Systems with Time Delays"*:

1. Decomposes the delay $\tau$ as $\tau=kT+\rho$ with $0\le\rho<\tau$
2. Absorbs the fractional delay $\rho$ into $H(s)$.

I ask how it is done the second step (if it is known), so how are calculated the coefficient of the numerator

$$ 0.1393 z + 0.1199 $$

and why that algorithm adds a zero to the transfer function and increases the order of the numerator to compensate the fractional delay.
Actually, the algorithm seems provide good results:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can I show you how to do $\LaTeX$ markup for your math?  And then you'll use that in the future?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson of course, thank you very much,  sorry, it is my first question!

Comment: Hay, just FYI, you had the $z$ is the numerator in your original posting.  Removing it from the numerator is just like multiplying by $z^{-1}$, which adds a delay of one sample to the transfer function.  Does that enter into your accounting of total delay?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson no, it is exactly 1/(0.25918178 −0.74081822068), because the ZOH introduce a delay in the tf.

Comment: A Zero-Order Hold is really about the continuous-time domain, where you have $H(s)$, not $H(z)$.

Comment: Sorry @robertbristow-johnson I do not understand your point. I need to find 
$$ {(1-z^{-1}) \mathcal{Z}{ \left\\{ \mathcal{L^{-1}}  \left\\{ \frac {1}{s}  \left(\frac{3}{3+s} \right) \right\\}\right\\}}} $$  and this result in  $$ \frac{0.25918178}{z−0.74081822068} $$ . No z at numerator.

Comment: I'm just saying that your original post, before I converted your text equations into $\LaTeX$, had a $z$ factor in the numerator.  I translated that accurately, ***then*** you removed it.  When you removed it, it was just like you added a one-sample delay, or multiplied by $z^{-1}$.

Comment: Is this the expression you meant to say? $$ (1-z^{-1}) \mathcal{Z} \left\{ \mathscr{L^{-1}} \left\{ \frac{1}{s} \left( \frac{3}{3+s} \right) \right\} \right\} $$

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero-order hold (ZOH) discretization is the same as the step-invariant method, which means that the step response of the discrete-time system equals the continuous-time step response at the sample instants. That's what is shown in the figure in your question.

The calculation of the discrete-time transfer function is performed as follows: factoring out a delay of $20$ samples, we're left with the following continuous-time transfer function:

$$H(s)=\frac{3e^{\tau s}}{s+3},\qquad \tau=0.05\tag{1}$$

The Laplace transform of the step response is

$$G(s)=\frac{H(s)}{s}=\frac{3e^{\tau s}}{s(s+3)}=e^{\tau s}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+3}\right)\tag{2}$$

The corresponding step response is

$$g(t)=\left(1-e^{-3(t+\tau)}\right)u(t+\tau)\tag{3}$$

For the ZOH (step-invariant) discretization we require the step response of the discrete-time system to be

\begin{align*}
g_d[n] = g(nT) &= \left(1-e^{-3(nT+\tau)}\right)u(nT+\tau)\\
&= \left(1-e^{-3\tau}\left(e^{-3T}\right)^n\right)u[n]\tag{4}
\end{align*}

where $T$ is the sampling interval.
The discrete-time unit step sequence $u[n]$ equals $u(nT+\tau)$ because $|\tau|<T$.

The $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $(4)$ is

$$G_d(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}-\frac{e^{-3\tau}}{1-e^{-3T}z^{-1}}\tag{5}$$

The transfer function of the discrete-time system is

\begin{align*}
H_d(z)=(1-z^{-1})G_d(z) &= 1-e^{-3\tau}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1-e^{-3T}z^{-1}}\\
&= \frac{1-e^{-3\tau}+\left(e^{-3\tau}-e^{-3T}\right)z^{-1}}{1-e^{-3T}z^{-1}}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

With $\tau=0.05$ and $T=0.1$ you obtain exactly the numbers returned by Matlab.

Comment: If found myself Friday this same solution, I would write it, but you come earlier. Happy that I was right! Thank you.